# Why no Web Applications rep on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

On [Geographic Information Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems), my commitment shows a contribution from [Food and Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking), but not from [Web Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications). What is the reason?

Answer (score 4):

I believe a site is only shown when you have >=200 reputation on it. So I'm guessing your cooking rep is greater than (or equal to) 200, but your webapps rep is not, and that's why webapps doesn't show up on Area 51.

Comment: Too bad. I had high hopes for the 100 point association bounty :-)

Answer (score 0):

These sites aren't formally members of the network until they survive public beta -- that takes 60 to 90 days.

See

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Well, cooking hasn't survived (yet) but it is listed. Is that a bug?

Comment: Same with programmers